# Deny database access to all users but sa/admin

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

How can I deny the access to a database for all the users except for the sa BY CODE? I know how to do it by using the interface in management studio, but I need to have it on the script.

Comment: so, you want to `revoke` access for everyone except a single user?  and you know for certain that user is `sa`?  You know, *for certain*, that `sa` exists on the instance(s) in question?  I ask this since you presumably are looking for code that can run against multiple instances, otherwise why are you *mandating* code.  Not that code is bad, I'm just trying to clarify your intent to prevent us from shooting you in the foot.

Comment: Also, what version of [tag:sql-server] ?

Comment: Yes, sa exists and is for a school project and i need to run the script on a virtual machine the teacher is going to run for us, so it all has to be on code. And yes, revoke access for everyone except sa. Sql server 2014

Comment: If this is for a homework assignment you should probably try to determine these things through either (a) looking in the manual (RTFM), or (b) doing a google search.  Asking for the answer is not really helping you learn how to do figure it out.

Comment: As i told you before, i know how to do it and researched it, but i cant find out how to do it just by coding, thats what im looking for to, i came here because i was unable to accomplish it by google searching.

Comment: i've found out how to deny all the databases for a single user, not only one database, i know how to allow one of them by using: `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::yourDB TO hello;`

Comment: This question needs to be more specific: are you looking to restrict access to a single database, or the whole SQL Server instance? Specifically just to the 'sa' login, or anyone with admin (CONTROL SERVER) or database owner permissions? A screenshot of what you're doing in SSMS might help clarify your question too.

Answer (score 6):

I'm reluctant to provide this code since it could be used to incorrectly deny access to everyone, if you don't have the 'sa' password, or if the 'sa' user is disabled, or if SQL Server logins are not permitted.

The following code will generate T-SQL statements to disable the logins for every Windows User, Group, and SQL Server login that is not the 'sa' user:

```
SELECT 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(sp.name) + ' DISABLE;'
FROM sys.server_principals sp
WHERE sp.principal_id > 100
    AND sp.is_disabled = 0
    AND sp.type IN (
        'U' -- Windows user
        , 'G' -- Windows Group
        , 'S' -- SQL user
        );
```

In order to actually revoke access to these accounts, you will need to copy-and-paste the results into a new command window and run them via F5

I'm purposely not adding code to automate the last part since this could easily be used to lock yourself out of your SQL Server.  If you wanted to automate it, you could search for dynamic SQL, and `EXEC (@var)`.

Answer (score 3):

The following is not exactly a match for you but it might be useful. A SQL-server database can be put into single user and restricted user modes. Single user as the name suggest means only one user can connect to it. Restricted means only users in sys_admin and db_owners can connect to it.

This can be achieved by executing:

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]
SET SINGLE_USER;

ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]
SET RESTRICTED_USER;
```

Keep in mind these scripts will not execute immediately as for example the single user one will be blocked if more than one user is connected. It will have to wait for all users to disconnect before going into SINGLE_USER mode.

To force these scripts add the `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` clause.

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]
SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

These scripts can be used in emergencies to block access to the database so you can get in and fix things. Helped me a lot years ago when two disks in a RAID 5 went sour.